# How to create a Dialog with a multichoiceitem list of Images with their names stored in internal memory in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an activity that further triggers a dialog which contains a list of images with their names . I want to select more than one image. Currently I used .setSingleChoiceItem method using an adapter which extends BaseAdapter but it will make only one choice to be selected please is there any way out that I can convert the same program for selecting multiple items? I am totally new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code ..... 
I think it would be helpfull for you..

final AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

```
    build.setTitle("List selection");
    build.setCancelable(true);
    final String[] string = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    final boolean data[] = new boolean[3];

    build.setMultiChoiceItems(string, data,
            new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked == true) {
                        data[which] = true;
                    } else {
                        data[which] = false;
                    }
                }
            });
    build.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i] == true) {
                            Log.v("MIS", "Item Checked "+string[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    build.show();
```